# Crash during didSelectRowAtIndexPath with custom index path

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Just stuck with an issue on my project.

I have a tableview with a list of countries. When you select a country it should add a checkmark accessory to the newly selected country. This all works fine.

However, I would like the old country's accessory to be set to none however I am having an issue getting this sorted.

My code is:

```
let oldCountry = countryList.countries.filter({c in c.countryName == profileCountryID })
let countryKey = oldCountry[0].countryID

let oldselectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(index: countryKey))!

oldselectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
```

The app crashes on this line:

```
let oldselectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(index: countryKey))!
```

The countryID is in a struct to allow me to find to array number

```
struct Country {
    var countryName  : String
    var countryID    : Int
}

public struct CountryLibrary {
    var countries: [Country]
}

let countryList =

CountryLibrary(
    countries: [
        Country(countryName: "Afghanistan", countryID: 0),
        Country(countryName: "Albania", countryID: 1)
```

])

Please can you assist in helping me remove the accessory for the previous row?

Thanks

Comment: Does it crash only when you had no country selected or even when you had a country selected? And what is `profileCountryID`?

Comment: You need to specify the section too NSIndexPath(forRow:countryKey, inSection:0)

Comment: profileCountryID includes the country name, eg United Kingdom or France

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that your `NSIndexPath` declaration is one for a "one-node" indexPath. What you require is a TableView indexPath which is declared as:

`NSIndexPath(forRow: <#Int#>, inSection: <#Int#>)`

So you might want to try the following:

```
let oldselectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: countryKey, inSection: 0))!
```

Comment: Thanks for the amendment. The code works for a short while. If no country has been selected before then tap a country the checkmark appears. Select another country and the old checkmark removes and the new country receives a checkmark.

HOWEVER, as soon as I close the view or restart the app then every time I select a country the app crashes on that line of code.

Comment: Hmmm, it's kind of hard to figure out why without seeing more of the code. As it stands, there should be no problem unless the `countryKey` is nil at some point. You are explicitly unwrapping `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and if `countryKey` was nil, you would get a crash for sure. If **that** is the problem, then you should either always have a value in `countryKey` or, check for nil before trying to assign `oldselectedcell` and changing it's `accessoryType`.

Comment: Hi. It look like its nil. In the Xcode debug window it shows the correct values when the app crashes. I've actually narrowed down that it only crashes if you select another row about 20 away from the previous (give or take a couple). Select rows in this range and it works perfectly. Here is a screenshot: [link](http://i60.tinypic.com/314whkz.png)

Comment: Just  what is in [this screenshot](http://oi60.tinypic.com/314whkz.jpg) I posted before

Comment: At the bottom right of Xcode, you have a small square with a bar in it. That opens the console.. I'd like to see the console output when the exception happens if possible.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. You are indeed correct and it is trying to unwrap a nil value. "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Why would the code work though when selecting a row close to the previous and not when selecting a row about 20+ away?

Comment: I found this and it looks like the culprit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188893/tableview-cellforrowatindexpathindexpath-return-nil

Comment: Yes, this must be it!